# simple-job-board Plugin throws an error on live server

Tags: plugins, hosting

**simple-job-board** Plugin throws an error on live server (on local server everything is working fine). 
The error occurs in *template-function* file. It doesn't recognize **$default_path** variable.
Here is the error log:

> Use of undefined constant **DIR** - assumed '**DIR**' in /wp-content/plugins/simple-job-board/public/partials/simple-job-board-template-functions.php on line:

And the part of the code in which **$default_path** goes undefined:

```
// Get default template
if (!$template && $default_path !== false) {
  $default_path = $default_path ? $default_path : untrailingslashit(plugin_dir_path(dirname(__DIR__))) . '/templates/';

  if (file_exists(trailingslashit($default_path) . $template_name)) {
    $template = trailingslashit($default_path) . $template_name;
  }
}
```

> Warning: include() [function.include]: Filename cannot be empty in /wp-content/plugins/simple-job-board/public/partials/simple-job-board-template-functions.php on line:

```
include( locate_simple_job_board_template($template_name, $template_path, $default_path) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you're using very old PHP version.

Why do I think so? Because the first warning says that `__DIR__` is unrecognized. It's one of PHPs magical constants and it should contain the directory of the file.

It was introduced in PHP 5.3.0, so if such error occurs, then you have to be using older version.

And this problem causes another one... `$default_path` is set to `DIR/templates/` instead of correct path to `templates` folder. So the next condition (checking if file exists) is false and the `$template_name` is never set...

**How to fix that problem?**

Upgrade your PHP version. 5.6 is the least version that is still supported (only security support).

http://php.net/supported-versions.php

Comment: I thought I must rollback the version of the plugin not php. It helped, thanks

Comment: Thanks Ani Naslyan, i roolback the plugin one version back and error disappeared.